# Update multiple rows without changing id value

Tags: php

We have Table like below :

[image]

Once we click on "**Submit**" button , I am displaying **random** numbers below column "**tracking id**" using below query , its working fine:

```
$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_id = '$r' WHERE id ='1'");
$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_id = '$r' WHERE id ='2'");
```

But when i use below query, its not updating....

```
$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_id = '$r' WHERE id ='$id'");
```

**Code :**

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>order</th>
<th>payment</th>
<th>generate</th>
<th>tracking id</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['payment_type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form method='post' action='new1.php'>
 <input type = submit>
</form> </td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['tracking_id'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

**new1.php**

```
<?php
$id = $row['id']; 
$r = mt_rand(1000,9999);

$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_id = '$r' WHERE id ='$id'");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're not including the details in the form

```
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>order</th>
<th>payment</th>
<th>generate</th>
<th>tracking id</th>

</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['payment_type'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    if (empty($row['tracking_id'])) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='new1.php'>";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['tracking_id'] . " </td > ";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table >";
?>
```

And you also need to modify **new1.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$r = mt_rand(1000,9999);

$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_id = '$r' WHERE id ='$id'");

?>
```

Comment: Also i need one more help , once we update the value, second time it should not allow to update, how to do that ?

Comment: This is working great, also its disappearing `submit` button under `generate` column..... thats what i also needed..... but once we click on `submit` , random number displaying below `generate` column , but it should display under `tracking` column..... please check that..........

Comment: Thanks a lot, If every developers in the world do coding as fast as you, than it will awesome.....